# how to calculate distance between two points using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, dictionary, distance

I have laravel blade where I get 2 lat,long using `<td> {{ $order->location_url }}</td>` and `<td> {{ $order->location_url_ot }}</td>`
and location_url is latlong in this form "31.5929345,74.3536356"

I want that when my bootstrap page is loaded, it should automaticly calculate distance in meters and return in `<td> distance </td>` How can I do that in javascript?

I have this distance formula

```
public function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
      $dist = acos($dist);
      $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
      return $miles;
  }
}`
```

How can I pass `$location_url` in this function and return miles or meter?

Comment: Cant you just use this function to calculate the distance in PHP and pass the result as another variable to your template?

Comment: no im interny still learning

Comment: Formula for computing straight line distance in javascript: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (equivalent to the PHP you posted, unless you want driving or walking distance).  What is `$location_url`?

Comment: @HamzaQureshi What i meant was - why do you need to calculate it in javascript when you already have php function for that. Call that function with the two points, pass that distance to blade template and display it alongside the 2 points.

Comment: yes you are right i did not think of now i use it

Comment: Google Maps APIs provide a distance matrix service that calculates distances between 2 points using JavaScript. You can check it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix